# reduction from $\#permanent _{-1,0,1}$ to $\#permanent _{0,1,2,3,\dots,n}$

Tags: complexity-theory

i want to prove the reduction  from $\#permanent _{-1,0,1}$ to $\#permanent _{0,1,2,3,\dots,n}$ and from $\#permanent _{0,1,2,3,\dots,n}$ to $\#permanent _{0,1}$ ( to prove that $\#permanent _{0,1}$ is$\#pcomplete$) but i dont see how to do that
?The permanent of a matrix $A=\{A_{i,j}\}$ is defined as
\begin{equation*}
     \sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\prod_{i=1}^n A_{i,\sigma(i)}
 \end{equation*}

Comment: could you share the definition of #$permanent$?

Comment: @Aishgadol,The permanent of a matrix $A=\{A_{i,j}\}$ is defined as 
 \begin{equation*}
     \sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\prod_{i=1}^n A_{i,\sigma(i)}
 \end{equation*}

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by *#permanent*.  Do you mean the problem of computing the permanent?  Or do you mean something else?  I suggest you add a self-contained definition to your question.

Comment: What research and reading have you done?  Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-completeness_of_01-permanent?  the paper "The Complexity of Computing the Permanent" by Leslie Valiant?  searched for lecture notes on the problem?

Comment: yes@D.W. imean problem of counting permanent and when i say $\#permanent_{0,1}$ i mean counting permanent of matrix xith enties 0and 1

Comment: yes @D.W.yes i read the paper but still dont undertood  how to do reduction from $\#permanent _{-1,0,1}$ to $\#permanent _{0,1,2,3,\dots,n}$ and from $\#permanent _{0,1,2,3,\dots,n}$ to $\#permanent _{0,1}$

Comment: Please don't reply in the comments.  Please [edit] your question to improve it.  I don't understand what "counting permanent" means.  A good way to specify a problem is to list the inputs to the algorithm and the desired output from the algorithm.

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/166807/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53962/5038.  [Simultaneously posting a similar question on multiple sites is likely to be frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).